# sharepoint 2013 Control Display Template : how to know how many items we'll get

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, display-templates

**What i Want :**
I would like a custom menu on my home page.
I would like to display 4 images (and links) (coming from a custom link application) in a square. (like at every edge, a couple image/link)
Not like a simple list (see this :

- MyImage1.jpg MyLink1
- MyImage2.jpg MyLink2
- MyImage3.jpg MyLink3
- MyImage4.jpg MyLink4
  )

**What i have :**

So, i've made my custom link application which contains several columns like URL, notes, ImageUrl.

On my Home, i've made a WebPart of category "Report de contenu" -which should be **Content Report** in english, i guess- and a component "**ContentSearch**".

This WebPart is displayed with a custom Control template -which is a copy of **Control_List.html**- and a custom Item template -which is a copy of **Item_Picture3Lines.html** .

What is my question :
In Control_List.html, in the js, we have this :

```
var ListRenderRenderWrapper = function(itemRenderResult, inCtx, tpl, i)
{
        var iStr = [];
        iStr.push('<li>');
        iStr.push(itemRenderResult);
        iStr.push('</li>');
    return iStr.join('');

}
```

This renders every item as a li, but with all its special displaying (defined in Item_Picture3Lines.html)
I would like to render these items in a 2x2 table.
like

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td id=Myitem1>
         <!-- All my content, displayed by the item display template -->
      </td>
      <td id=Myitem2>
         <!-- All my content, displayed by the item display template -->
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id=Myitem3>
         <!-- All my content, displayed by the item display template -->
      </td>
      <td id=Myitem4>
         <!-- All my content, displayed by the item display template -->
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I know table are ugly etc..

**My question is..**
How can i know the number of items that will be displyed in my control Display Template to determine whether i have to end my  and open a new one?

**Thanks a lot**, i'm a new beginner in Sharepoint, please be kind! :)

Answer (score 2):

your items (from the control template) are here

```
ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].ResultRows
```

the number of items that will be displayed is

```
ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].ResultRows.length
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT! I've found a solution to my problem (which is : create a li display inline, instead of an ugly table), but i am sure i will need this in the future.
If you have some documentation on how ctx works (which datas etc...), I will be glad and grateful if you could share them with us.
Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was also looking for this.